# Filtering pandas rows based on first row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:
[image: sample table]

And I just want all the rows based on the first row, so I wrote

```
df[(df['product']==df.loc[[0],['product']])&(df['program_code']==df.loc[[0],['program_code']])]
```

etc for all the other columns that isn't sum

Which should return the first ~30 rows
Instead I get Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

If I check to see if there boolean, which you would think as I'm comparing the values to itself and they're homogeneous, I get:
[image: New table]

It's like my dataframe somehow shifted and I get two nan's.  I'm sure there's a feature whereby this shifting is important, but I don't even know when I do it.

And even if you solve that.  I get:
[image: Further mystery]

But if I HAND type it, I get
[image: Success]

Success!
So maybe the item isnt' right
[image: Pandas aren't hard]

Comment: `And I just want all the rows based on the first row`. Sorry, this isn't at all clear. What *exactly* is the logic you wish to apply?

Comment: It was how do I get this to work: df[(df['program_code']==df.loc[[0],['program_code'])&(df['product']==df.loc[[0],['product']])], but I think its that I should use df.iloc[0]['program_code'] instead.  Why?  I don't know

Comment: try replacing `df.loc[[0], 'program_code']` with `df.program_code.iloc[0]` throughout.

Comment: Yes, Yakym, that was the answer.  I figured it out just then too.  Why iloc doesn't work like loc is a mystery to me, but I'm sure this feature enables untold complexity in analysis